# Adding blur effect on a part of image in QML

Tags: qml, qtquick2, blur

I am trying to add some blur effect on an image in my QtQucick app. Following is a simple snippet that can load an image, and put on it a custom polygon. What should I add to my code to make inside of the polygon looks blurry!

Thanks in advance.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window
{
    id: main_window

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var mpoints: [Qt.point(20, 20), Qt.point(20, 300), Qt.point(300, 300), Qt.point(300, 20)]

    Image
    {
        id: m_image

        anchors.fill: parent

        source: "file:///C:/Users/LeXela/Pictures/test.jpg"
        cache: false
    }

    Canvas
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPaint:
        {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, main_window.width, main_window.height);

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(mpoints[0].x, mpoints[0].y)
            for(let i = 1; i < mpoints.length; i++)
                ctx.lineTo(mpoints[i].x, mpoints[i].y);
            ctx.closePath();

            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Qt5, use [FastBlur](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-fastblur.html). If you're using Qt6, try [MultiEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qtquickmultieffect/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the Image twice with the second instance (1) sampled at a lower resolution by setting `sourceSize`, (2) then, you can render a clipped version of the lower resolution image by defining a polygon using `ShapePath` and using that with `OpacityMask`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Page {
    property list<point> mpoints: [Qt.point(100, 150), Qt.point(300, 150), Qt.point(200, 250)]

    Image
    {
        id: img
        width: 400
        height: 350
        source: "butterfly.png"
    }
    
    Image {
        id: blur
        width: img.width
        height: img.height
        source: img.source
        sourceSize: Qt.size(32, 32)
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id: mask
        width: img.width
        height: img.height
        Shape {
            id: polygon
            ShapePath {
                fillColor: "red"
                strokeColor: "red"
                startX: mpoints[0].x; startY: mpoints[0].y
                PathLine { x: mpoints[1].x; y: mpoints[1].y }
                PathLine { x: mpoints[2].x; y: mpoints[2].y }
            }
        }
        visible: false
    }
    
    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: mask
        source: blur
        maskSource: mask
    }
}

// butterfly.png : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephenquan/stephenquan.github.io/master/images/qt/Original_butterfly.png
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Here's a version where the polygon vertices can move:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Shapes
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Page {
    property list<point> mpoints: [Qt.point(100, 150), Qt.point(200, 50), Qt.point(300, 150), Qt.point(200, 250)]
    property int msize: 20
    
    Image
    {
        id: img
        width: 400
        height: 350
        source: "butterfly.png"
    }
    
    Item {
        id: blur
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            width: img.width
            height: img.height
            source: img.source
            sourceSize: Qt.size(img.width / blurSlider.value, img.height / blurSlider.value)
        }
        visible: false
    }
    
    Item {
        id: polygon
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false
        Repeater {
            model: mpoints.length - 2
            Shape {
                property point firstPoint: mpoints[index]
                property point secondPoint: mpoints[index+1]
                property point lastPoint: mpoints[mpoints.length - 1]
                ShapePath {
                    strokeColor: "orange"
                    fillColor: "orange"
                    startX: firstPoint.x; startY: firstPoint.y
                    PathLine { x: secondPoint.x; y: secondPoint.y }
                    PathLine { x: lastPoint.x; y: lastPoint.y }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    Repeater {
        model: mpoints.length
        Shape {
            property point thisPoint: mpoints[index]
            property point nextPoint: mpoints[(index + 1) % mpoints.length]
            ShapePath {
                strokeColor: "blue"
                strokeWidth: 2
                startX: thisPoint.x; startY: thisPoint.y
                PathLine { x: nextPoint.x; y: nextPoint.y }
            }
        }
    }
    
    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: blur
        maskSource: polygon
        invert: invertCheckBox.checked
    }
    
    Repeater {
        model: mpoints
        Rectangle {
            x: modelData.x -msize / 2
            y: modelData.y -msize / 2
            width: msize
            height: msize
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "red"
            border.width: 2
            DragHandler {
                onGrabChanged: {
                    switch (transition) {
                        case 1:
                        break;
                        case 2:
                        Qt.callLater(movePoint, index, parent.x + msize / 2, parent.y + msize / 2);
                        parent.x = -msize / 2;
                        parent.y = -msize / 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    footer: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            CheckBox { id: invertCheckBox; text: "Invert" }
            Slider { id: blurSlider; from: 1; to: 10; value: 10 }
            Label { text: "Blur %1".arg(blurSlider.value.toFixed(1)) }
        }
    }
    
    function movePoint(index, newx, newy) {
        mpoints[index] = Qt.point(newx, newy);
    }    
}

// butterfly.png : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephenquan/stephenquan.github.io/master/images/qt/Original_butterfly.png
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Clever approach! Well done. Thank you so much. :-)